# Is there a way to instruct nuget push to use a custom config file location without passing the -ConfigFile argument?

Tags: nuget

Rationale - I am actually using `Publish-Module` PS function to publish a PS module. This function internally calls either nuget.exe or `dotnet.exe nuget` to actually push the PS module package.

Unfortunately, this function does not pass the `-ConfigFile` argument effectively forcing us to use the user level `$env:APPDATA\NuGet\NuGet.config` file.

Why the file matters? The repo requires Access Token to authenticate. I do not know any other way except record it in the NuGet.config file. If there is one that would spare the config file at all - I will gladly use it.

So I am looking for one of the following:

- Provide a custom NuGet.Config location to NuGet.exe without `-ConfigFile` argument. E.g. - through a well-known environment variable.
- Eliminate the need for NuGet.Config at all by providing the Access Token in the environment or some custom file location, but not the user level NuGet.Config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

1. Create a temp directory
2. Generate an empty (just with the root element) nuget.config there
3. Change to that directory using both `[IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory` and `Set-Location`. It is important to use both this API **and** the Powershell native `Set-Location`
4. Call Publish-Module from that directory.